# Should I use SPContext or ClientContext?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to extract data from a SharePoint Online list in a simple Console application (.net 4.5).
For this, I have added a reference to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime`.
The following does what I need...

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(siteUser, securePass);

Web site = ctx.Web;
ctx.Load(site);
List lst = site.Lists.GetByTitle("SomeList");
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = @"<View>
                    <ViewFields>
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                    </ViewFields>
                </View>";

ListItemCollection items = lst.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["Title"]);
}
```

I now need some more complex query with a `Query` and a `RowLimit`. In this more complex `CamlQuery`, `RowLimit` seems to be ignored.

```
<View>
    <RowLimit>1000</RowLimit>   
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name='Title' />
      <FieldRef Name='ProductName' />
      <FieldRef Name='GroupName' />
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <Where>
          <Neq>
              <FieldRef Name='GroupName' />
              <Value Type='Lookup'></Value>
          </Neq>
      </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

I can't get the RowLimit to work. All examples I come across are using SPContext that has the ability to set the RowLimit on a SPQuery object.

The SPContext needs a large SharePoint dll to work while ClientContext is already present in Visual Studio (using 2015) and has much smaller DLL's.

So..

**1. When should I use SPContext?

 2. Is there some reason that RowLimit does not work in the CamlQuery above?**

**Edit 13/08 13:15**
The problem does not seem to be with the RowLimit but with the query itself.

```
<Neq>
    <FieldRef Name='GroupName' />
    <Value Type='Lookup'></Value>
</Neq>
```

This does not seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to exclude items those `GroupName` lookup field is empty,  replace the [Neq Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452901.aspx) :

```
<Neq>
    <FieldRef Name='GroupName' />
    <Value Type='Lookup'></Value>
</Neq>
```

with [IsNotNull Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms465807.aspx):

```
<IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='GroupName' /></IsNotNull>
```

**Example**

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = 
                       "<View>" +
                          "<RowLimit>1000</RowLimit>" +
                              "<ViewFields>" +
                                  "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                                 "<FieldRef Name='ProductName' />" +
                                 "<FieldRef Name='GroupName' />" +
                               "</ViewFields>" +
                               "<Query>" +
                                  "<Where>" +
                                      "<IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='GroupName' /></IsNotNull>" + 
                                  "</Where>" +
                               "</Query>" +
                          "</View>";

var items = list.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```